# Obtain the edges removed by using k-core in Networkx

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx, subgraph

I'm using Networkx's k-core to remove nodes of degree < 2.

```
n=20
G = nx.gnm_random_graph(n=20, m=30, seed=1)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()

retain_node_ids = [1, 8]
G.add_edges_from([(u, v) for u in retain_node_ids for v in (n, n+1)])
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

G = nx.k_core(G, k=2)

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, pos=pos)
plt.show()
```

k-core returns the subgraph. But I would also want to obtain the list of nodes and edges removed while using k-core.

Any suggestions will be highly useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nx.k_core` only returns the corresponding maximal subgraph. In order to find the nodes and edges that are not included in the resulting subgraph, you'll have to find the node differences between both graphs, and from there find the edge differences. Using an example `nx.gnm_random_graph`:

```
diff_nodes = set(G.nodes()).difference(H.nodes())
print(diff_nodes)
# {2, 4, 11, 19}

removed_edges = {e for e in G.edges() for n in diff_nodes if n in e}
print(removed_edges)
# {(2, 8), (4, 18), (7, 11), (13, 19)}
```